# addEventListener Срабатывая с двух кликов

Tags: javascript, foreach, popup, onclicklistener, queryselectorall

Только сильно не смейтесь))) Я только учусь)))
Вот такая функция в HTML все работает отлично)

```
 let imagesBox = document.querySelectorAll('.imagesBox')
  imagesBox.forEach(popup => popup.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
  }))
```

Я перенес эту функцию в Ract и она тоже работает но только при двойном нажатии. Я понимаю что выполняется два действия вначале 'onClick' потом 'clikc'
Помогите пожалуйста. Необходимо что бы все работало с первого клика) Спасибо.

```
    <div className="imagesBox" onClick={OpenBaner}>


    function OpenBaner() {
      const imagesBox = document.querySelectorAll('.imagesBox')
      imagesBox.forEach(popup => popup.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
      }))
    }

export default OpenBaner
```

...

Answer (score 3):

```
function OpenBaner(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```